# Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.3 table-reflow issue in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I was trying the below code in mobile view not able to fix the table-reflow issue in mobile view. Any suggestion will be really appericiated

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTrs0.jpg)

View code at [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZXGwZ)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <table class="table table-reflow">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Bonus</th>
            <th>Total</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr scope="row">
            <td>665</td>
            <td>Amit Shah</td>
            <td>10000</td>
            <td>1000</td>
            <td>11000</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: was the codepen updated to show the solution? I'm having trouble figuring out what the original problem was/is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution for you using media query. Hope it might help you.
check the [CODEPLY](http://codeply.com/go/gVdLCQJhBt) link

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 544px) {
  .table-reflow thead,
  .table-reflow thead tr,
  .table-reflow tbody tr {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue in BS4 alpha:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20510

One workaround is to set a fixed width to the table to prevent it from wrapping.

http://www.codeply.com/go/WX8ByNRqMy

Comment: I do not want the scroll to be coming in but thanks for your reply :)

Comment: If you don't want to scroll, just don't use the table-responsive around it